# Angular Component/Service to return image content to URL

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-routing, angular-components

I am trying to setup a component/service to return base64 image content to img.src calls from html.

I have images stored on google Firebase/Firestorage which can only be accessed via method calls to get the download-url for passing to img.src.

I also have a div there I am passing html to [innerHtml]. In the html I am passing are paths to sources on my domain. The content for innterHtml is also coming from Firestorage.

I want to create a route+component to handle this. Returning the base64 to the query.

I have used toPromise to force the sequential execution and have the imgSrc variable set before ngOnInit completes.

Early completion of ngOnInit will cause a 404.

I am currently getting a 404.

**Code:**

*Page code:*

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="content" [innerHtml]="pageContent"></div>
<div>
```

*content:*

```
pageContent = "<div><h1>Hello</h1><img [src]="/path/to/images/hello.jpg"></div>
```

*route/path in routing module:*

```
  {
    path: 'path/to/images/:filename',
    component: ImageComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Image',
    }
  },
```

*Image Component:*

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireStorage } from "@angular/fire/compat/storage";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { ImageService } from "../../services/ApiCalls/Images/images.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'image-component',
  template: '{{imgSrc}}',
})
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private imageService: ImageService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private firebaseStorage: AngularFireStorage,
  ) {

  }

  public imgSrc: string;
  isImageLoading: boolean;

  getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.httpClient.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }

  createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      return reader.result.toString();
    }, false);

    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
    return reader.result.toString();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.toPromise().then(par => {
      const filename = par['filename']
      this.firebaseStorage.ref(`images/${filename}`).getDownloadURL().toPromise().then(src => {
        this.getImage(src).toPromise().then(blob => {
          this.imgSrc = this.createImageFromBlob(blob);
        })
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the right approach, specifically the innerHtml part. The content of innerHtml will NOT be processed by Angular therefore your [src] in there won't work. I'm also not really understanding what you want to do with that specific route for /path/to/image. That will completely unload everything (the current component) and you'll end up with... ? Well... I'm not even exactly sure but it doesn't seem right? It seems what you need to just a service that fetches stuff, converts to it to what you need and simply returns it to a component that renders.

Comment: I have a working instance which retrieves all instances of img from the DOM, checks if the path of the image is one of the ones on firebase, if so updates it with the firestorage url. But this results in the initial img queries to fail and log.

Comment: I'm not looking to process the text in innerHTML, I want to setup a route mocking the path in the html content, which will get the firebase url, get the image, convert to base64 and respond so the DOM is render a base64 image via src

Comment: Still, this: <img [src]="/path/t..." in innerHtml will fail.